# Does Java `public static` top-level classes?

Tags: java, hibernate

Does Java support `public static` top-level classes?
AFAIK - No, But in the Hibernate documentation there are lots!

If you do a 'public static class' search [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity) then you'll see:

```
@Entity(name = "Book")
public static class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String author;

    //Getters and setters are omitted for brevity
}
```

Does anyone have a good explanation of why this is?

Comment: those are _inner_ classes, most probably

Comment: @Eugene, but it is not obvious for a newbie :)
In DOCs classes are presented without outer class

Comment: In Java, the `static` modifier on a nested class means that it does not belong to a particular instance of its containing class. On a top-level class it would have no meaning (and is therefore not allowed).

Comment: _Every_ top-level class is more or less static.

Comment: @khelwood, moreover - it is not allowed - but DOCs confuses people

Comment: @ALZ Perhaps someone should tell the authors of those docs that they are writing bad examples.

Comment: if you are at the point of using hibernate, you are, by definition, no newbie; at least it is assumed you know such basic things... imo.

Answer (score 1):

No Java doesn't allow the `static` modifier on top-level classes, only on nested classes.

As @Eugene said in the comments, the documentation probably contains snippets of nested classes.

Answer (score -1):

> Does Java support public static top-level classes?

No, because instance of `Class<T>` needs to be instantiated.

> But in the Hibernate documentation there are lots!

I think they should be meant/implied to be inner classes; however, I'm also really surprised and disappointed (of JBoss) with why the documentation has such an unclear and confusing representation of those classes.. it's definitely not obvious that they are meant to be inner.

### However!

Rest assured, top-level class can*not* be static; It will not even compile.**

---

### A bit more details

Reason behind this is how Class concept is designed to be working in Java. Also, it's important to understand how the mechanism of class-loading works; namely, how `Class<T>` type is incorporated into Java's class definition.

When you run your Java application, number of things happen, and one very important *thing* is the process of Class Loading, which is done by corresponding Class Loader.

Every time your code interacts with some type, **for the first time**, JVM loads corresponding bytecode into the memory, and after that, Class Loader generates special object of type [`Class<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) which is output of the class-loading step, and which is instance of `java.lang.Class`.

### What does this mean?

This means, that Class Loader needs to instantiate special object(s) of type `Class<T>`, for each class definition, you've got in your application.

Those instances of the `Class<T>` type, which JVM creates initially, are created only once and are then stored into the memory. `Class<T>` object simply has a meta-information about the loaded class. Meta-information is Class name, names of all super classes, names of all defined methods and etc.; and every time you invoke `new` instruction, followed by the class name, instance of `Class<T>` is used (with its metadata) to *instantiate* your object, and this instance (`Class<T>`) is needed because it stores/holds all the information about your class, i.e. it is a Class Definition for your program's runtime.

### Takeaway

P. S. static members are not instantiated, therefore, class definition (which you name as a top-level class) can **not** be static.

Comment: But `Class` objects exist for nested types. I don't understand your argument about `Class`.

Comment: Yes and no... inner type definitions are members of the outer types, so they *belong* to their enclosing types.